# runit spawns the process twice after reboot

Tags: reboot, runit

After reboot runit respawns the program it has launched already. There are no error messages in the service log. The program registered as a service starts working properly but after about 10-15s it is being restarted by runit.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the process is "daemonizing" / "backgrounding".

- Shut it down using `sv d <service>`
- Confirm stopped (ps)
- Start it with `/var/service/<service>/run`

If the job stays running - that is good.

If it "finishes" and control returns to the shell, that is bad - you need to reconfigure the process not to run in the background.